# Is it possible to style a web part title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, css, calendar, classic-experience

On my home site, 3 sections: The banner and 2 web part containers.

- The first container includes some text and links which were organized into two sections whose headings were bolded.
- The second container includes a Calendar list web part.

I would like to Bold the word Calendar, but I cannot find where I would do that. It's worth mentioning that this is for SharePoint online and this particular page is in the classic view.

Side question: If I were to modernize this page, would I be able to style the calendar list name on this page? Or can it be done with SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **classic experience**, If you already enabled the **[custom scripts](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-custom-script-based-missing-features-in-sharepoint-online/)**, you can add `script editor web part` with the below CSS:

```
<style>
.ms-WPTitle {font-weight:Bold !important; } 
</style>
```

> **Note:** The above style will bold all web parts title in the page.

---

**For a specific web part**,

You can get the `web part id` for your `calendar web part` using IE developer tool(F12), then use the below style

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartTitleWPQ3
{
   font-weight:Bold !important;
}
</style>
```

> **Note:** Replace the `WebPartTitleWPQ3` with your own that you got using F12 Developer tools.